# How to do a clean app restart (iOS 6.1)?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I realized an app for iOS. It all goes well, works like a charm... until the device is restarted! When I manually close the app (for example, on my iPad I slide four fingers upwards, visualize the menu showing the app "alive", hold the icon of the app and press the red badge, terminating the app) and I try to open it again this is what happens to me:

- First the app remains stuck on the last page visited before closing the app (I cannot tap buttons on the tab bar or do anything else)
- Then, the only thing I can do is tap the Home button and try to open the app again
- At this point all I get is a perfectly black screen

The restart seems to be not a real restart, or not to be clean. This is totally meaningless to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: pressing the home button does not terminate the app. to terminate an app hold the icon in the app switcher until a red badge appears, then press it.

Comment: do you have any code in `applicationDidEnterBackground` or `applicationWillEnterForeground`?

Comment: maybe you forgot to call `makeKeyAndVisible` on the window?

Comment: When you press close button, it does not close your app but sends it into background. To close your app you need to press home button twice and delete it from there.

Comment: Yes. The restart i mean happens for me in this way: for example, in ipad i slide four finger toward up, visualize the menu showing the app "alive", hold the icon of the app and press the red badge, terminating the app. The problem happen when i tap again the app icon to open it again. No, i have no code within those functions. When the app goes in background, anyway, all works well. The only problem is after terminating and reopening.

Comment: Do you use some persistent data when app start?

Comment: When app start i check if the user want the push notification, check an xml online for new data, fill some data in a sqllite db on the device, and add an image to document folder. I guess the problem is not strictly in the app start for, i repeat, the flow is: i use the app, then i terminate it, then when i reopen it, it show the last view i visited before terminating the app and remain stuck. Then if i tap Home and try again to open the app i get only a black screen.

Comment: Without a code is hard to say! Theoretical guess - there is empty local db (or any other persistent data) when you start fresh installed app, trying to restart app something could go wrong when reading saved data.

Comment: I know, it's terrible not getting even a clue on what is causing the problem. Normally all the app proceed without a single warning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Xcode, when it runs an app, attach to it a debbuger which prevents it to close normally and causes problems in the reopening. Thank you very much to this guy who pointed out the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176137/1272105

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :**

Remove your application by press Hold down Application iCon From simulator/device 
And then re-install app. and check it worked or not ???

If your view display with black screen then give it backGround Color `redColor` or as u wish.

Comment: Ok, how can i avoid that when my app is closed, opening it again causes it to give a black screen? Or, at least, how can i understand what is going on in the app when it do this? (This happen outside the control of the xcode console)

Comment: He/She is not asking to restart the app by code, please read the question carefully

Comment: Removing the app and readding it, make it work again, but as i terminate and restart the app, it happens again. I guess it is not a view problem: the black screen i mean is totally black. I cannot even see the tabbar.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem seems to me not related to an identificable part of my code. I'm trying to guess what the problem can be...

Answer (score 0):

Its iOS app natural behavior only.

When you press Home button on device, While running any iOS app it goes in background but the The app is still in background and its save application's state.

So if you Tap agin app's icon you will get the last screen where did you leave it.

Now, if you want to Restart the app from initial you need to clear it.

Go this way.

1. Just double press device's Home button you can see running apps on bottom like this

[image]

2. For delete particular app, you simply press and hold, you can see red (-) icon on app

[image]

just click on that and you are on way.

3. Now press Home button and Go to Start app!!

Comment: Is exactly what i do ^^' And at that point, instead of start again, the app remain stuck on its last screen. Totally blocked. The only thing i can do at that point is pressing home to get back. Then when i press the app icon trying to restart it i get a totally black screen and there's no way to start the app again.