# Can i display error occurred within an app if i'm not launching it with Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, error-handling

I have a problem with my app: if i launch it with Xcode all goes well. If i manually terminate The app and then i try to open it again(not running it with Xcode, but simply tapping the icon button) instead of reopening from the start, The app shows me the last screen i opened before terminating it and remain stuck, totally blocked. In that moment, i'm not under control of Xcode console: how can i visualize an error eventually occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your app from Xcode, it attaches a debugger to your app. This prevents the app from closing normally. You'll need to press the stop button in Xcode to detach the debugger and let the app quit so you can launch it from the iPad normally.

Comment: Can't believe it... I've done a partial test and works like a charm. I'll do a full test as soon as i can! Thank you a lot, you saved the day!

Comment: Test done. The problem is exactly what you said. Thank you very much!